Why does an rdkit function only work when I import something else?
There is something seriously strange going on here with RDKit's imports that I don't understand.
I am using some basic functionality (as per their documentation) like so:
from rdkit import Chem

# Create a molecule from a SMILES pattern (arbitrarily chosen for this example)
mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles('CCCC')

# Calculate its molecular weight
print(Chem.Descriptors.ExactMolWt(mol))

Except, this doesn't work.

AttributeError: module 'rdkit.Chem' has no attribute 'Descriptors'

However, if I add an import line at the top: from rdkit.Chem import Descriptors. Now it works.

58.078250319999995

Note, I HAVE NOT CHANGED ANY OF THE REST OF THE CODE. Only the import, which I do not use directly!
What on earth is going on here?

Python submodules are not automatically imported when you import the parent module.  The author can do that if desired (in this case, Chem/__init__.py would need to contain an import statement for Descriptors) - but that's not always a good idea, it would mean that EVERYBODY that imports Chem would suffer the import time and memory use of Descriptors, whether or not anything in the submodule is actually needed.

This question is similar to: Why do Python modules sometimes not import their sub-modules?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

try:
from rdkit import *

# Create a molecule from a SMILES pattern (arbitrarily chosen for this example)
mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles('CCCC')

# Calculate its molecular weight
print(Chem.Descriptors.ExactMolWt(mol))

Output:
58.078250319999995

